# Apply class to an element based on content length in html(without jQuery)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html-table

We are created a table with a large number of columns and rows. And some columns have large length of data. But we want to set the row height of the table should be same. So we created a div with y-scroll and put the large column data into it. Right now we identified some columns have large data and wrapped this cell value with Y-scroll div. But we want to do it dynamically i.e if the content length exceeds the width this warp it with a Div which have scroll. We prefer something in HTML or CSS not in jquery.

below html shows the large data column value wrapped with div y-scroll.

```
 <td class="tagstd" style="text-align: center; vertical-align:top;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:0px;max-height:40px"> <div class="yscroll">
                                          @Model.IND_APP_PASS_STATUS.RS_TP
                                        </div>
</td>
```

Comment: *"without jQuery"* Then don't tag the question `jquery`!

Comment: What part of this are you stuck on?

Comment: There's no way to warp elements, so lets assume it's wrap, and there's no way to wrap elements with CSS, but you could of course do it with HTML, but not dynamically. Maybe the best option would be to check the string length on the serverside, and wrap it in ASP